# Variable selection of columns in a sql query

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access

In ASP.NET, can a 'select-query' be dynamic as follows ?
This throws an error, how can this be achieved?

```
SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 30 [date],**[@tc]** FROM [tbl_TC] WHERE ([ID] = ?) ORDER BY [date]">
<SelectParameters>
**<asp:QueryStringParameter Name="@tc" QueryStringField="tc" />**
<asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="pid" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't so that in *SQL*, let alone ASP.NET.  You'll have to generate the SQL by inserting the column name into the string.

I don't know of a way to do that declaratively - you're probably going to have to do the binding in code-behind and build the SQL dynaimcally:

```
string SQL = "SELECT TOP 30 [date], [" + tc + "] FROM [tbl_TC] WHERE ([ID] = ?) ORDER BY [date]";
```

Comment: sounds right, but the [] around [" + tc + "]  will likely make the database engine take that to mean one column, even if it's a list of columns.  removing the [] from the string here and including them in the tc variable should work

Comment: @Twelfth I included the brackets because the code in the question had them, which makes me think that the _intent_ is to only have one column.

Comment: Thank you guys. I was trying to get it done on ASP side which is not possible , so i have to dynamically select columns in the code (vb)

Answer (score 0):

Use a command object and replace the placeholder text with the column names.

```
Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("Your Connection String")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim reader As SqlDataReader

Dim qryString = "SELECT TOP 30 [date],**[@tc]** FROM [tbl_TC] WHERE ([ID] = [?]) ORDER BY [date]"

qryString = qryString.Replace("**[@tc]**", "yourcolumnnameshere").replace("[?]", "datequerystringhere")

cmd.CommandText = qryString
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

sqlConnection1.Open()

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
' Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

sqlConnection1.Close()
```

MSDN Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx

Comment: Thanks @GJKH for the complete solution, however i feel its more straightforward to append  the query string with a variable as suggested by Stanley.